# Squeak System Browser Questions

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

I am using (a school modified version of) the "Squeak By Example" (SBE) image for a OOP/OOD class. However, my System Browser is missing a few features that appear in SBE. I assume there are some configuration options that can get them back for me, but I can't find them yet.

My questions are:

1) How do I get the buttons back? In the bottom pane there should be a bunch of button (browse, senders, implementors, versions, ..., source). My buttons are missing.

2) How do I get the small workspace area above the buttons to appear? There is supposed to be an area that I can type in, below the top panes, and above the buttons, but it doesn't appear.

Thanks in advance!

Robert

Edit - I did fool around in the Preferences Browser and tried a lot of settings. I managed to make the buttons come back and then later got that small (unknown name) workspace pane back, but I have no idea how. I have tried to systematically turn stuff off again to find out what setting(s) controlled what, but I was unable to determine what controlled either problem. So even though I have it working, I would like some squeak/smalltalk knowledgeable person to let me know how to control these as it might help me learn...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"In the bottom pane there should be a bunch of button (browse, senders, implementors, versions, ..., source). " -- switch on the optionalButtons preference in the preferences browser.

The "area that I can type in, below the top panes, and above the buttons, but it doesn't appear" sounds like the annotation pane - this gives you summary information about the method you're currently viewing, and it's controlled by the annotationPanes preference. Alternatively you may be referring to the Mercury Panel which is used for fast navigation to other classes and methods; this is (of course :-) controlled by the mercuryPanel preference.

If you've been messing around, you may also find that you now have an incorrect system browser selected. Squeak has a choice of browsers which can act as the System Browser. You can choose between them by clicking the menu button on the System Browser and selecting "Choose new default Browser". Open a new browser window to see what effect this has had.

Comment: Awesome! It sure helps to know the names...typical learning curve I guess. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to try a [Pharo image](http://pharo-project.org/download) which has everything configured the way you want by default.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the Preferences Browser? It should be in the main system menu. You can alter all sorts of things via this browser, including which buttons appear in teh system browser?